# Trouble writing a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a definition to use as the options for a select field in a form.

```
Miniature.rb
  has_many :manufacturers
  has_many :lines
end

Line.rb
  belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

When adding a @miniature to a @line I want the drop down to only display the @lines that belong_to a @manufacturer that corresponds with that @miniature.

This is my attempt

```
def mfr_lines
    @mfrs = @miniature.manufacturers.map
    @mfr_lines = @mfrs.lines.map
end
```

The first line seems to work, it combines all the @miniature.manufacturers
What I need to do then is get all the lines for EACH @manufacturer and join them into one array. I can't work out how to do the EACH bit or how to join them. Tried a number of possible solutions to no avail. Any help much appreciated.

It wants to work ultimately like this in the view

```
<%= f.select :line_id, @mfr_lines, include_blank: true %>
```

Comment: In your Miniature model, are you actually saying "have_many" or using the proper rails helper `has_many`?

Comment: sorry, I'm saying has_many. I just put it that way here so it read as a sentence. Bad form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@hoffm's solution is good, but a little improved version can be used:

```
def mfr_lines
  @lines = Line.where(manufacturer_id: @miniature.manufacturers.pluck(:id))
end
```

And its usage for the select with `options_for_select` **(1)**:

```
f.select :line_id, options_for_select(@lines.map{|l| [l.name, l.id] }), include_blank: true
```

**Why is it better** than `@miniature.manufacturers.map(&:lines).flatten`?

- `manufacturers.map(&:lines)` actually call the method `.lines` (triggers a SQL query) on each `manufacturer`. If you have 10 of them, it will call 10 times `SELECT * FROM lines WHERE lines.manufacturer_id = <id>`,
- `Line.where(manufacturer_id: @miniature.manufacturers.pluck(:id))` is and will always be only 2 combined queries:

  ```
  # @miniature.manufacturers.pluck(:id) (2)
  SELECT id FROM manufacturers WHERE manufacturers.miniature_id = <@miniature.id> ;
  # This returns a list of IDs

  # Line.where(manufacturer_id: list_of_ids)
  SELECT * FROM lines WHERE lines.manufacturer_id IN (<list_of_ids>) ;
  ```

---

In overall, the following Ruby on Rails code:

```
Line.where(manufacturer_id: @miniature.manufacturers.pluck(:id))
```

Triggers the following SQL:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM lines 
  WHERE lines.manufacturer_id 
  IN ( SELECT id 
         FROM manufacturers 
         WHERE manufacturers.miniature_id = <@miniature.id> )
```

---

References:

- **(1)** [`options_for_select` documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)
- **(2)** [`.pluck` documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you MrYoshiji. Just what I had in mind but didn't have the mastery to code. So neat to use where to do a simple compare but only possible when plucking the :ids. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `map` without a block returns an enumerator, which it doesn't sound like you were expecting. If I understand what you're after, this is the way to go:

```
def mfr_lines
  @miniature.manufacturers.map(&:lines).flatten
end
```

This code retrieves the array of all manufacturers associated with the miniature, and then maps each of those to an array of their lines. The result is an array of arrays of lines, which we then flatten to get an array of lines over which you can iterate.

Comment: It looks to have them there in the drop down but isn't treating them as @lines any more. Can we do this whilst still keeping them as a collection of @lines?

Comment: Assuming the associations you laid out in your question, the method I wrote returns an array of lines.

Comment: Yes they are lines but whereas if I pass @lines to my select field it knows to put the Name automagically and it accepts the selected line as an input, this shows #<Line:0X007fb etc and if selected and submitted returns SQLite3::ConstraintException: